# Jenkins integrate with JIRA - Couldn't add Outgoing authentication for Application links in JIRA version 6.4

Tags: jenkins, jira

I could't able to add Outgoing Authentication of following credentials Service Provider Name, Consumer Key, Shared Secret,Request Token URL, Authorize URL..etc, while the creating application links for Jenkins. Also I couldn't able to see Application links/Creating reciprocal links in Jenkins.

Jenkins ver. 1.580

JIRA version 6.4

JIRA plugin for jenkins 1.39

JiraTestResultReporter plugin for jenkins 1.0.4

Answer (score 0):

I was able to integrate Jenkins and Jira successfully via the SOAP service of Jira

I did not create an application link for Jenkins. Application links in Jira are applicable only for Atlassian Suite of products and not external products like Jenkins.

Jenkins talks to Jira via SOAP service something looks like the URL below

yourjirahost:yourjiraport/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2

Any username password that can connect to a particular issue

Comment: Kindly post the steps of configuration to integrate Jenkins with JIRA

Comment: A detailed step by step procedure is listed in the plugin wiki below Please follow the steps as mentioned in this wiki page and let me know if you still need some help .. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JIRA+Plugin

Comment: I have configured jira test result reporter plugin with Jenkins. After build gets failed, reporting JIRA issue is done and build status is FAILURE. But issue is not seen anywhere in jira.
Jenkins ver. 1.580
JiraTestResultReporter plugin 1.0.5
JIRA: 6.4
Console Output:
BUILD FAILED
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
**[JiraTestResultReporter] [DEBUG]**
**[JiraTestResultReporter] [DEBUG] Creating issue in project QAA at URL 
https://example.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/**
**[JiraTestResultReporter] [INFO] Reporting issue.
**[JiraTestResultReporter] [INFO] Done.**
Finished: FAILURE